# Lazy Load does not work after loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

Guys I'm using 2 script to make the page faster:
The first one is

The first one is Load More Posts or Infinite Scrolling to Blogger I found here https://helplogger.blogspot.com/2016/09/load-more-blogger-posts-or-infinite-scrolling.html

code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function resizeThumb(e,n){for(var t=document.getElementById(e).getElementsByTagName("img"),a=0;a<t.length;a++)t[a].src=t[a].src.replace(/\/s72\-c/,"/s"+n+"-c")}window.labelfx=function(){var e=function(e){var n=e||{},t=n.url_blog||window.location.host,a=n.id_labelcontent||"#labelfxn";$.ajax({url:"http://"+t+"/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var n=e.feed.category,t="";if(void 0!==n){t="<ul class='labelx'>";for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)t+='<li><a href="/search/label/'+encodeURIComponent(n[i].term)+'" target="_blank">'+n[i].term+"</a></li>";t+="</ul>",$(a).html(t)}else $(a).html("<span>No Label!</span>")},error:function(){$(a).html("<strong>Error Loading Feed!</strong>")}})};return function(n){e(n)}}(),resizeThumb("main",250),labelfx(),function(e){function n(n){e.getScript("http://"+n+".disqus.com/blogger_index.js")}function t(){s||(s=!0,o?(r.find("a").hide(),r.find("img").show(),e.ajax(o,{dataType:"html"}).done(function(t){var a=e("<div></div>").append(t.replace(l,"")),i=a.find("a.blog-pager-older-link");i?o=i.attr("href"):(o="",r.hide());var p=a.find(d).children(".date-outer");e(d).append(p),resizeThumb("main",250),window._gaq&&window._gaq.push(["_trackPageview",o]),window.gapi&&window.gapi.plusone&&window.gapi.plusone.go&&window.gapi.plusone.go(),window.disqus_shortname&&n(window.disqus_shortname),window.FB&&window.FB.XFBML&&window.FB.XFBML.parse&&window.FB.XFBML.parse(),window.twttr&&window.twttr.widgets&&window.twttr.widgets.load&&window.twttr.widgets.load(),r.find("img").hide(),r.find("a").show(),s=!1})):r.hide())}function a(){if("item"!=_WidgetManager._GetAllData().blog.pageType&&(o=e("a.blog-pager-older-link").attr("href"))){var n=e('<a class="loadpost" href="javascript:;" style="text-decoration:none;font:11px Open Sans, sans-serif;letter-spacing:1px;padding:10px 20px;background:#000000;color:#ffffff;">MOSTRAR MAIS ARTIGOS</a>');n.click(t);var a=e('<img src="'+i+'" style="display: none;">');(r=e('<div style="display:block;text-align:center;margin:20px auto;"></div>')).append(n),r.append(a),r.insertBefore(e("#blog-pager")),e("#blog-pager").hide()}}var i="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6_Eha7PSRy0/WXI6jskHE9I/AAAAAAAAMB0/6iFQ2qywS2kaNA2evWgsUb51zjRFf69cQCLcBGAs/s1600/loader.gif",o="",r=null,d="div.blog-posts",s=!1,l=(e(window),e(document),/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi);e(document).ready(a)}(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
```

The second is the lazy load I found on this site https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html

see the code

```
<script>
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i &lt; imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

I did everything the site recommends and both scripts work fine when I open the site.

But when I click load more articles, which is the first script, it loads the articles only without images.

Is it any missing conflict or code?

They could look at the codes and see if there are any conflicts in both.

Remembering that they work when I open the site, but when I click load more articles the article appears without image.

Comment: If you are dynamically loading the articles when needed, you probably wont benefit much from lazy loading the images anyway. Also, there is not a `loading` attribute for the img tag, eg, `loading="lazy"` which is [supported by chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr)

Comment: Got it, I'm looking for a lazyload that works on blogger but just found this one.